# how to change jstree icon

Tags: javascript, jstree

fllow the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#demo1").bind('loaded.jstree', function(e, data) {
            // invoked after jstree has loaded
        $('#demo1 ul>li').addClass('topMenu');
        $('#demo1 ul>li').css('background-image','/Images/SgTLink_After_Login_07.png');

        }).jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "contentType": "application/json;",
                    "url": "/Desktop/MenusFunc.aspx/GetAllNode",
                    "data": function(node) {
                        return '{ "operation" : "get_children"}';
                    },
                    "success": function(retval) {

                        return retval.d;

                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data"]
        });

    });
</script>
```

i got the image for every treeNode and save it in db,how can i change it? thx
Sorry if the question seems basic but I find the documentation hard to follow when trying to do basic things. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after read the documentation of jstree I want to share you that there is not enough scope to use node icon for different node. I think for this you need to hack the css using jquery what you did in your code to do for all ul>li background image change. Use Firebug you can see an extra html node for set the icon field e.g. 'ins' and you have to set the icon image over there.To access the 'ins' nod you have got 'li' id to track it down using jquery selector. Hopes it will give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class in the 'li' node. And use the following code to change the node style.

```
$(".XXX > a > ins").removeClass('jstree-icon').addClass('jstree-XXX');
```

The style of "jstree-XXX" should be added in the **style.css** or the **style.min.css** (depends on your usage).

Maybe this can help you. Thanks.